# Python Selenium WebDriver unable to catch TimeoutException, with Timeloop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a function to fetch the page source of a webpage using Selenium WebDriver and run it every 120 seconds using Timeloop.

**scraper.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException
from timeloop import Timeloop
from datetime import timedelta

url = "https://example.com"

@tl.job(interval=timedelta(seconds=120))
def scrap_content():
    try:
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        web_driver.get(url)
        web_driver.quit()
    except WebDriverException as e:
        print("Web Driver Exception: ", e.Message)
        return
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Timeout Exception: ", e.Message)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tl.start(block=True)
```

I was thinking I caught the `TimeoutException` properly, but then the logic sometimes still crash with `TimeoutException` on the line `web_driver.get(url)` (indicated as line 52 below):

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/scraper.py", line 52, in scrap_content
    web_driver.get(url)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 449, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 297.904
  (Session info: headless chrome=114.0.5735.90)
```

How come? I am clueless. How can I handle the `TimeoutException` and let the Timeloop to continue to run the function even after the `TimeoutException` occurs (supposed the exception is caught and the error message is displayed instead of crashing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something on that page that doesn't finish loading. You can get around that by changing the pageLoadStrategy:

```py
options.page_load_strategy = "none"
```

For reference, you can learn about that here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/

The full example they showed is this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Make sure to have the quotes like this: `"none"`, (not to be confused with a Python `None`, which this isn't).

Note that you can also change the default timeout values for a page load from 300 seconds (the default), to something else like this:

```py
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
```

(That'll make the `Timed out receiving message from renderer` error message appear sooner if it's going to happen.)